# Preliminary data on how the Hot Network Question list affects this site's scores and views

Tags: discussion

Since getting onto the HNQ now generates a database entry, it's possible to see how that affects scores and views and so I thought I would put together some statistics on how it works.

I am going back to comparing the questions asked since 2019-02-28 since that is the earliest data entry.

```
select sum(viewcount) from posts
left join posthistory on PostHistoryTypeId = 52 and posts.id = postid
where posts.creationdate > '2019-02-28' and PostTypeId =1
```

The questions in each category are listed below.

[Link to Hot Questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/1025304)

[Link to Non Hot Questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/outdoors/query/1025302)

Number of Questions

- Total 51
- Hot 11 - 22%
- Not Hot 40 - 78%

Total Score of questions

- Total 373
- Hot 202 - 54%
- Not Hot 171 - 46%

Average Score of question

- Total 7
- Hot 18
- Not Hot 4

Number of views per question

- Total 43077
- Hot 37832 - 88%
- Not Hot 5245 - 12%

Average number of views per question

- Total 844
- Hot 3439
- Not Hot 131

Average number of answers per question

- Total 1
- Hot 4
- Not Hot 1

Total number of answers per question

- Total 90
- Hot 44 - 49%
- Not Hot 46 - 51%

Answer (score 3):

Bravo!  TNS is to analyze what makes a question hot.  My guess is it is the sexiness of the title.  It would be interesting to take a non-hot question and edit the title to see if that makes it hot.  Or, if the rules don't allow edited questions to be eligible for hotness, write a new Q very similar to the old Q, but jazz up the title.

I have no idea how to transform the title of *How to Clean Trail Running Shoes* to make it hot, but *Camping Alone in the Wilderness in the USA* could become How to *Evade  Prosecution until the Statute of Limitations has Expired for Collusion with the Russians by Camping off the Grid in a Remote Wilderness*. :)

Comment: The hotness formula is explained in [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/241919), and the biggest factors are total upvotes and time. (Un)fortunately, clickbait titles usually work well for fishing upvotes... until someone edits to clarify the real title :/

Comment: Wow, I hope you won't go into the business of click-baiting - you'd be a force :)